# Fibonnaci Sequence

Tags: java, fibonacci, println

I'm a absolutly beginner in java and i want to write a code with the acm.libary, which is about the fibonacci sequence.

The result is very nice for me, but i want only print the last number of the sequence. I don't know how.
If the user type n = 5, the result need to be 8.
If the user type n = 8, the result need to be 21.
In my program it is the last number, but the program also prints all the previous numbers.

I hope you can understand me :D

Thank you in advance!

```
 int a = 1;
 int b = 0;

public void run() {
    int n = readInt ("n: ");
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        println (fibonacci (n));
    }
}

private int fibonacci(int n) {
    int c = (a) + (b);
    a = b;
    b = c;
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Maybe that helps: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/Fibonacci.java.html

Comment: Your implementation of `fibonacci` is wrong.

Comment: @Maroun: It is not implemented by simply using the definition of fibonacci numbers, but I don't see that it calculates wrong numbers. If the implementation is wrong there must be at least one wrong number. Which one?

Comment: @mm759 Maybe the name is confusing; looking only at the `fibonacci` method, it's clear that it doesn't calculate the fibonacci number of the input.

Comment: @Maroun: I agree that it does not calculation the n-th fibonacci number unless it is successively called as in the method "run".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the body of the loop by this:

```
if (i == n) {
  println (fibonacci (n));
} else {
  fibonacci (n);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {
    int a = 1;
     int b = 0;

    public int run() {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = s.nextInt();
        int value =0;
        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            value =  fibonacci (n);
        }
        return value;
    }

    private int fibonacci(int n) {
        int c = (a) + (b);
        a = b;
        b = c;
        return c;
    }

    public static void main (String arg[])
    {
        Test t = new Test();
        System.out.println(t.run());
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks! This is working also fine, without the acm.libary.